# Get realtime updates with Cloud Firestore with asyncio

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, python-asyncio

How can I run this [example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/cb47b2edfda3cda16bbec25a772a4cf657ba268f/firestore/cloud-client/snippets.py#L750-L771) through asyncio? The error I got on startup:

```
name col_snapshot is not defined
```

sample:

```
    async def on_snapshot(col_snapshot, changes, read_time):
         logger.debug('Received updates')

    col_query = db.collection(u'cities')
    query_watch = col_query.on_snapshot(await on_snapshot(col_snapshot, changes, read_time))
```

Update: [Async callbacks example](https://github.com/googleapis/python-firestore/issues/3)

```
import os
import asyncio

from loguru import logger
from google.cloud.firestore import Client

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS']='E:/Python/listener_firebase/creds.json'

async def callback(col_snapshot, changes, read_time):
    logger.debug('Received updates')

    for change in changes:
        if change.type.name == 'ADDED':
            logger.debug(f'New document: {change.document.id}')

    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    logger.debug('Finished handling the updates')

Client().collection('cities').on_snapshot(callback)

while True:
    pass
```

This doesn't work for me:

```
tch.py:568: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'callback' was never awaited
  self._snapshot_callback(keys, appliedChanges, read_time)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Comment: Did you tried with the [Documentation example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#python) by using `threading`?

Comment: `on_snapshot` doesn't do anything asynchronous, so there's really no point it defining it as a coroutine, but if you're doing something that just isn't included above, the fix is that you need to call `on_snapshot`: `await on_snaphost(arg1, arg2, arg3)`.

Comment: @dirn if i use `query_watch = col_query.on_snapshot(await on_snapshot(col_snapshot, changes, read_time))` then I get  `NameError: name 'col_snapshot' is not defined`

Comment: You need to define variables before you can use them.

Comment: @dirn But in the example, they are passed implicitly. How can I get them?

Comment: I think what’s happening in the example (it’s really hard to follow without proper indentation) is that `col_query.on_snapshot` wants a callback. In that case, your call would look identical to the example. The problem, though, is that you need to pass it a regular callable, not an awaitable. Do you need your code to run in an existing event loop or can you spawn a new one each time? Do you even need to use asyncio with your callback (it currently doesn’t use it)?

Comment: @dirn Yes, I need to use asyncio

Comment: Please answer my other question: "Do you need your code to run in an existing event loop or can you spawn a new one each time?"

Comment: @dirn I need to run code in an existing event loop. Also I have updated my question

Answer (score 1):

As it's written, your code shouldn't use asyncio at all. If, however, `await asyncio.sleep(1)` is there to simulate some I/O heavy code that takes advantage of asyncio, your options here aren't great. The first solution would be to use an asyncio-aware client for Firestore. I have no idea if one exists. Assuming one doesn't, and, as you say, you need to use an event loop that is already running, you need to define a synchronous function (since that's what needs to be passed to the client's `on_snapshot`) that schedules your asynchronous callback with the event loop.

```
import os
import asyncio

from loguru import logger
from google.cloud.firestore import Client

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS']='E:/Python/listener_firebase/creds.json'

async def asynchronous_callback(changes):
    logger.debug('Received updates')

    for change in changes:
        if change.type.name == 'ADDED':
            logger.debug(f'New document: {change.document.id}')

    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    logger.debug('Finished handling the updates')

def synchronous_callback(col_snapshot, changes, read_time):
    asyncio.create_task(asynchronous_callback(changes))

Client().collection('cities').on_snapshot(synchronous_callback)

while True:
    pass
```

Really, though, your best option is not to use asyncio for your callback since the Firestore client is already running your code synchronously.